# Unable to test amount transfer in solidity in mocha. But manual test are running fine

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

My contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Escrow{
    address payable public dev;
    address public website;
    address public customer;
    uint public amount;

    constructor( address payable _dev, address _customer,uint _amount){
        dev = _dev;
        website = msg.sender;
        customer = _customer;
        amount = _amount;

    }

    function deposit() payable public{
        require(msg.sender == customer, "Only customer can add money");
        require(address(this).balance <= amount, "Money can not exceed given amount");
    }

    function sendMoney() public{
        dev.transfer(amount);
    }

}
```

Deployment script

```
const Escrow = artifacts.require("Escrow");

module.exports = function (deployer, network, accounts) {
  deployer.deploy(Escrow, accounts[1],accounts[2], 1000);
};
```

When I do manual testing on the remix website it's working fine. But when testing `sendMoney` function it's throwing error

```
const Escrow = artifacts.require("Escrow");

contract("Escrow", (accounts) => {
  let escrow = null;
  const [website, dev, customer] = accounts;
  before(async () => {
    escrow = await Escrow.deployed();
  }); 

  it("Check money send", async ()=>{
    try{
      const prevDevBalance = web3.utils.toBN(await web3.eth.getBalance(dev))
      await escrow.sendMoney({from:accounts[0]})
      const newDevBalance = web3.utils.toBN(await web3.eth.getBalance(dev))
      assert(true)
      return
    }catch(e){
      assert(false)
      console.log("ERRORR",e)
    }
  }) 
});
```

Sometimes tests are successful but 90% time throwing this issue.

```
  1) Contract: Escrow
       Check money send:
     Uncaught AssertionError: Unspecified AssertionError
      at checkError (test/index.js:7:5)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)



UnhandledRejections detected
Promise {
  <rejected> AssertionError: Unspecified AssertionError
      at checkError (test/index.js:7:5)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
    showDiff: false,
    actual: null,
    expected: undefined,
    uncaught: true
  }
} AssertionError: Unspecified AssertionError
    at checkError (test/index.js:7:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  showDiff: false,
  actual: null,
  expected: undefined,
  uncaught: true
}
```

Comment: Have u deposited ether to the contract first ?

Comment: It would be easier if we saw what's the error, place `console.log("ERRORR",e)` before the `assert(false)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to initialize the contract, its constructor expects 3 arguments `address payable _dev, address _customer,uint _amount`.

Use this to deploy -

```
  before(async () => {
    escrow = await Escrow.new(dev, customer, "1");
  });
```

Comment: If i use .deployed then it will take deployed contract. And in migrations I have provided arguments. What is diff in you above code? Also I need to deploy my contract as website. how can I do that ?

Comment: It passes params for the constructor, did you do that on your deployed contract?

Comment: added the deployment script. I guess issue is i am not passing value on init and checking contract balance in require statement is issue. Will ping you if this was the issue